# How to build an "orignal" Ubuntu installer/live iso image?

Tags: live-cd, iso, livedvd

Where to I find the scripts to bootstrap and create an normal Ubuntu installer/live iso image?

Or in other words, how are the (X)Ubuntu default installer/live images build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, make a custom live CD from scratch. [This article in the Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) explains how.

However, you might prefer to start out with an existing live CD image, and [customize that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) (which is considerably faster and simpler).